# Почему элемент игнорирует flex-basis?

Tags: css3, flexbox

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему последний div при врапе растягивается во всю ширину контейнера, несмотря на flex-basis: 100px и flex-grow: 1? Я хотел бы, чтобы они переходили на другую строку не растягиваясь, как в этом примере: https://jsfiddle.net/nmjaxh9m/59, но не понимаю что делаю не так.

Мой код:

```css
.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
} 


.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item span {
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/280x280"><span>item</span></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/280x280"><span>item</span></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/280x280"><span>item</span></div>
<div class="item"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/280x280"><span>item</span></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, потому что в примере по ссылке max-width 300px, а у Вас - 100%. Вот на 100% и растягивается.

Comment: Возможно, но в примере и со 100% работает, если верить редактированию в jsfiddle

Comment: @Jenya, в примере по ссылке, если Вы обратите внимание, есть "костыль" - там напихано в конце много пустых a'шек - это чтобы казалось, что работает :)) Если Вы их удалите, будет как у Вас =)